# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection (Welcome & Economy code)

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

So I keep getting the error above concerning my discord js bot. I know it's to do with my economy code clashing with my attempt on making a welcome code but with my baseline knowledge not existing, I was hoping someone in the community could help with this.

The first line of code is my Guild codes (Drop down from Events), the first is guildMemberAdd.js and the code is:

```
    const profileModel = require('../../models/profileSchema');
    
    module.exports = async(client, discord, member) => {
        let profile = await profileModel.create({
            userID: member.id,
            serverID: member.guild.id,
            coins: 1000,
            bank: 0,
        });
        profile.save();
    };
```

The next file within the guild file is the message.js and the code within this is:

```
    require("dotenv").config();
    const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");
    const cooldowns = new Map();
    
    module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
      const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    
      if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
      let profileData;
      try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if (!profileData) {
          let profile = await profileModel.create({
            userID: message.author.id,
            serverID: message.guild.id,
            coins: 1000,
            bank: 0,
          });
          profile.save();
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    
      
      const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
      const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
      const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
      if (!command) return message.channel.send("This command does not exist!");
    
      if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
      }
    
      const current_time = Date.now();
      const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
      const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;
    
      //If time_stamps has a key with the author's id then check the expiration time to send a message to a user.
      if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
    
        if (current_time < expiration_time) {
          const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
    
          return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
      }
    
      //If the author's id is not in time_stamps then add them with the current time.
      time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
      //Delete the user's id once the cooldown is over.
      setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
    
      try {
        command.execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData);
      } catch (err) {
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
```

Next is the features folder which contains the welcome.js file and the code in this is:

```
    // "welcome.js" file within the "features" folder
    module.exports = client => {
        client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
          console.log(member.user.tag)
        })
      }
```

The next folder is the handlers folder which contains 2 files, the first is the command_handler.js and the code in this is:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
        const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
        for(const file of command_files){
            const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
            if(command.name){
                client.commands.set(command.name, command);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

The 2nd file is the event_handler.js and the code within this is:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
        const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
            const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
            for(const file of event_files){
                const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
                const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
                client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client))
            }
        }
    
        ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
    }
```

The final folder is the models folder which contains the profileSchema (for economy) and the welcome-channel.js file.
The profileSchema code is:

```
    //PROFILE SCHEMA--------------------------------------------------------
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
      serverID: { type: String, require: true },
      coins: { type: Number, default: 1000 },
      bank: { type: Number },
    });
    
    const model = mongoose.model("ProfileModels", profileSchema);
    
    module.exports = model;
```

and the welcome-channel.js code is:

```
    // "welcome-channel.js" file within the "models" folder
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    // We are using this multiple times so define
    // it in an object to clean up our code
    const reqString = {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
    const welcomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: reqString, // Guild ID
      channelId: reqString,
    })
    module.exports = mongoose.model('welcome-channel-tutorial', welcomeSchema)
```

The direct command for setting a welcome channel is setwelcome.js and the code is:

```
    // "setwelcome.js" file within the "commands" folder
    const welcomeChannelSchema = require('../models/welcome-channel')
    const cache = new Map()
    // An async function to load the data
    const loadData = async () => {
      // Get all stored channel IDs
      const results = await welcomeChannelSchema.find({})
      // Loop through them all and set them in our map
      for (const result of results) {
        cache.set(result._id, result.channelId)
      }
    }
    // Invoke this function when the bot starts up
    loadData()
    module.exports = {
        name: "setwelcome",
      requiredPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
      execute: async ( message, args, cmd, client, discord, profileData ) => {
        // Destructure the guild and channel properties from the message object
        const { guild, channel } = message
        // Use find one and update to either update or insert the
        // data depending on if it exists already
        await welcomeChannelSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: guild.id,
          },
          {
            _id: guild.id,
            channelId: channel.id,
          },
          {
            upsert: true,
          }
        )
        // Store the information in the cache
        cache.set(guild.id, channel.id)
        message.reply('Welcome channel set!')
      },
    }
    module.exports.getChannelId = (guildId) => {
      return cache.get(guildId)
    }
```

The moment I get the error is when i execute the command simjoin.js and the code for this is:

```
    // "simjoin.js" file within the "commands" folder
    module.exports = {
        name: "simjoin",
        requiredPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
        execute: ( message, args, text, client ) => {
          client.emit('guildMemberAdd', message.member)
        },
      }
```

**Be aware that the welcome code isn't finished, but from this moment it should still work but it doesn't due to the duplication key error which is why I need your help!**

Comment: can you provide an example of your documents in your database?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you connect using MongoShell you can query the data and see the raw output.  My question is - can you please provide the raw output of a document so we may see the target data structures?

Comment: Truthfully, I got no clue what I'm doing on MongoShell. I've used MongoDB Compass for everything but never really touched MongoShell. I've installed the Community one for Mongo and touched a few things on Shell but ultimately am just confused.